# Efficient way to find list of common items based on condition

Tags: c#, collections

I have List of List of Permissions i.e.  `List<List<Permission>> permisionLists` and each permission has property called `HasPermission`.
Each list of permission is identical except HasPermission property true/false for permission item.
What is the most efficient way to find out list of Permissions which has all HasPermission set to false in in permisionLists?

I have to find only permissions which has value set to false in every List.

```
public class Permission
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public bool HasPermission { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried below code but no luck,

```
disabledPermissions = from permisions in permisionLists
    from permission in permisions
    where permisionLists.All(l => l.Any(o => o.HasPermission ==false))
    orderby permission.HasPermission
    select permission;
```

Comment: To accomplish what you want, you have to iterate through all the elements and collect the ones meeting the expected condition. In C#, you can implement this in quite a few different ways (and depending upon the exact situation, some of these approach might be notably more efficient than other ones; difficult to tell in general terms though). Not trying anything and expecting us to solve all your problems for you is offtopic here.

Comment: If in a simple list of `Permission` (`permisionLists) you want to get all the elements where `HasPermission` is false you might do: `permisionLists = permisionLists.Where(x => !x.HasPermission).ToList();`.

Comment: @varocarbas the OP stated in the question that `permisionLists = new List<List<Permission>>();`. In the LinQ statement, `permisions` would be a local `List<Permission>`

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Thanks for the clarification. You know... when I have to come here to read the requirements 3 times because the OP is providing all the required information in a multi-step process, it is a bit difficult to keep the whole picture completely clear at each point (mainly when I was honestly expecting him to not do anything, because this is the usual behaviour; I am happy that the situation was different). Any suggestion for the OP or are you only focusing your efforts on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  modified cFrozenDeath answer as in his case I am getting duplicate permissions

```
permisionLists.ForEach(permissions => permissions.Where(p => !p.HasPermission).ToList().ForEach(permission =>
{
    if (!permisionLists.Where(permissionList => permissionList.Where(p => p.Id == permission.Id).FirstOrDefault().HasPermission).Any())
    {
           if (disabledPermissions.All(p => p.Id != permission.Id))
           disabledPermissions.Add(permission);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited once again: this should give you an idea on how you could filter the lists to search for the same id. This is likely not the best performance-oriented approach, but it should give you an idea:

```
permisionLists.ForEach(permissions => permissions.Where(p => !p.HasPermission).ToList().ForEach(permission =>
{
    if (!permisionLists.Where(permissionList => permissionList.Where(p => p.Id == permission.Id).FirstOrDefault().HasPermission).Any())
    {
        disabledPermissions.Add(permission);
    }
}));
```

The `ForEach` method executes the lambda expression for each item in the list. This filters explicitly only items in the list that has `HasPermission` set to false.

Comment: I +1ed mostly for your efforts, although this is not exactly a perfect answer IMO. The OP is asking about the most efficient alternative (-> you should read the whole question :)). Even by relying on LINQ there are many other alternatives, for example the contrary than what you tried: `disabledPermissions = permisionLists.Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.HasPermission)).ToList();` (isn't this quickly?). And what about other non-LINQ alternatives? Where is the efficiency comparison/analysis? Anyway... the question is asking for too much to be on-topic, so I guess that this is OK.

Comment: @varocarbas see my edit. The other linq version you posted is more or less the same as the one I posted originally. I should test with very big lists to know if there is a really gain in your version.

Comment: Your answer is more complete now. Although I am not so sure that what you are claiming is right: loops might be faster than LINQ in certain situations but this is very difficult to tell right away (and there are still many alternatives within LINQ and/or mixed LINQ + loop). Have you do some tests? If so could you please include the testing framework/testing conditions and results? You know... it is much better to not say anything than to output an absolute statement "this is faster" whose accuracy is not too high (and which might be easily misunderstood).

Comment: For small sizes, all the approaches (your initial LINQ, mine, the loops and even further alternatives) should deliver almost the same performance. There might be some differences with big enough inputs, but there is only one way to tell which one is faster: actually testing it. Sorry to be the bad-news bearer but your "is much faster " has no value here :) (don't get offended, this would be the case even with someone with much higher experience or rep here than you; like for example what happens with me, with 10 times more reputation than you. I have also to prove my statements).

Comment: @varocarbas just as you stated, getting the most efficient alternative is offtopic, but this is what I've tried: set `permissionLists` to 5000 default capacity, add 5000 `List<Permission>` to `permissionLists` and create 5000 items inside each `List<Permission>`. I tested with the `Stopwatch` class, using `sw.Elapsed.TotalMiliseconds`. In 4 tests, the double foreach won by .3 miliseconds minimum and .8 miliseconds maximum. Wanted to test with bigger collections, but VS complains with an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Thanks for your answer, but I am afraid ,I need  list of permissions(List<Permission> ) , you are returning List of list of permissions List<List<Permission>> by getting all disabled permission in each list.
I need list of permissions(having HasPermission == false)) in every List<Permission> i.e.permissions, Sorry for confusion caused.

AS I have mentioned in question, have to find only permissions which has value set to false in every List.

Comment: Your last comment is much clearer. Perhaps you should add all this information (what you tried, the differences you observed... basically this last comment + a couple of quick ideas) to your answer to help future readers to quickly get a proper picture.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath , I am afraid , I tried that too , the problem here it is adding permission when it is false without checking it in other lists. I want to check in remaining Permission lists also and when that permission is false in every PermissionList then only i have add them into disabledPermissions list

Comment: @RoshanGhangare so you want to compare whether the permission is set to false in every list? How do you compare the lists to see if it's the same permission? Do you want to do this by using he Id property?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, yes we can use that, as Id will be same in each permission list, I thought of getting count of permissions using Id in disabledPermissions list and compare it with count of List<List<Permission>> permisionLists , But not sure will that would be correct/efficient approach.......

Comment: @RoshanGhangare cFrozenDeath has been doing a lot of work here and your conditions are quite unclear. You should try to be a bit understanding. Also it seems that your instructions are a bit confusing. The first version of this answer (or my code above: `disabledPermissions = permisionLists.Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.HasPermission)).ToList();`) delivered exactly what you requested; that is "find out list of Permissions which has all HasPermission set to false in in permisionLists". cFrozenDeath has even brought it a bit further and tried to come up with the most efficient approach.

Comment: @RoshanGhangare Do some tests with the delivered codes (click on "edited x minutes ago" to see previous versions) and confirm that everything is OK. Note that this last version (presumably the most efficient one) delivers a different output which perhaps is not exactly what you want (as said your requirements are not clear). In any case, please remember that we are not here to solve your problems for you; perhaps you might have to adapt this answer to your specific needs.

Comment: @RoshanGhangare see my latest edit. That's only an idea and I'm not completely sure is what you want, but that's the best I could do. It's nice playing with LINQ. Thanks for the input varocarbas

Answer (score 0):

You use the word 'efficient' in your question. You will want to ask a question of the List and make sure that is only recalculated of the list content changes.

I'd consider creating a new class like so;

```
public class PermissionCollection : Collection<Permission>
{
}
```

Override the InsertItem, RemoveItem methods etc as shown in example 2 of [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx). Set a private Boolean like collectionDirty to true on any edit

Then add another property like

```
public bool HasAnyPermissions
{
    get
    {
            if (collectionDirty) {
                // recalculate here
                cachedAnswer = ...;
                collectionDirty = false;
            }

           Return cachedAnswer;
    }
}
```

This gives you a very effective way to make sure you're not performing an O(n^2) search, which the current suggestions suffer from.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, the following will be a quite effective way to achieve the goal with linear time complexity

```
var itemMap = new Dictionary<Guid, Permission>();
foreach (var list in permissionLists)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Permission other;
        if (!itemMap.TryGetValue(item.Id, out other) || (item.HasPermission && !other.HasPermission))
            itemMap[item.Id] = item;
    }
}
var result = itemMap.Values.Where(item => !item.HasPermission).ToList();
```

The same can be achieved with Linq, but will use more space due to groupings storage allocation

```
var result =
    (from list in permissionLists
     from item in list
     group item by item.Id into g
     where !g.Any(item => item.HasPermission)
     select g.First()).ToList();
```

I personally prefer the former (non Linq).